# Angular: Using index of ngFor throws error Expecting a numeric type

Tags: angular, typescript

After the latest Visual Studio Code update I get an error with a long ago written code in my Angular 8 app.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productItems; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="i % 3 === 0 " class="card-deck mt-2">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of productItems.slice(i,i+3)">
...
```

The variable "i" in lines 2 and 3 are marked as an error "Expected a numeric type ng(0)".

I am a bit clueless at the moment because the code is working as expected and "ng serve" and "ng build" successfully serve and build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular language service, there is a possibility of bugs.
There is a similar phenomenon issue.

[index value is not number error in template #460](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/460)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: whats the solutions, couldn't get